# Unity Web API - Register Service From Different Assembly

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm using web api 2 with unity 4.
My solution consists of project A and project B.
Project A contains a controller with a constructor requiring a parameter of type IA.
Project B conatins a class name A that inherites from IA.

I am trying to inject A into the controller, but failing as I'm receiving an error that the controller has no parameters less constructor.

This is the code I'm using in WebApiCongig.cs:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterTypes(
AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
WithName.TypeName,
WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,null,true);
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

When I'm using the following, everything works but this is not what I want, as now Assembly A knows the concrete type A, and the whole point is that it won't.

```
container.RegisterType<IA, A>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a bootstrapper for Unity WebApi like that:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(*******.Web.App_Start.UnityWebApiActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(*******.Web.App_Start.UnityWebApiActivator), "Shutdown")]

namespace ********.Web.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with WebApi when it is hosted in ASP.NET</summary>
    public static class UnityWebApiActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            // Use UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver if you want to use a new child container for each IHttpController resolution.
            // var resolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
            var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use Nuget, and install Unity Bootstrapper for WebApi [LINK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.AspNet.WebApi/)